# How it is correct to specify declaration for my namespace and the function in the second case?

Tags: c++

Look, I placed my namespace and the function before the `main` and this compiled successfully:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//==================================================
namespace Bushman{
    void to_lower(char* s)
    // Replace all chars to lower case.
    {
        const int delta = 'a' - 'A';                
        while(*s){
            if(*s >= 'a' && *s <= 'z') *s -= delta;         
            ++s;
        }
    }
}
//==================================================
int main()
// entry point
try{
    namespace B = Bushman; // namespace alias
    void B::to_lower(char* s);  
    char* str = "HELLO, WORLD!";
    B::to_lower(str);   
    printf("%s\n",str);
}
catch(exception& e){
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    return 1;
}
catch(...){
    cerr << "Unknown exception." << endl;
    return 2;
}
```

But if I placed my namespace and the function after the `main`, then I can't compile this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//==================================================
int main()
// entry point
try{
    namespace B = Bushman; // namespace alias
    void B::to_lower(char* s);  
    char* str = "HELLO, WORLD!";
    B::to_lower(str);   
    printf("%s\n",str);
}
catch(exception& e){
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    return 1;
}
catch(...){
    cerr << "Unknown exception." << endl;
    return 2;
}
//==================================================
namespace Bushman{
    void to_lower(char* s)
    // Replace all chars to lower case.
    {
        const int delta = 'a' - 'A';                
        while(*s){
            if(*s >= 'a' && *s <= 'z') *s -= delta;         
            ++s;
        }
    }
}
```

How it is correct to specify declaration for my namespace and the function in the second case?

Comment: Umm... I know it takes 30s to copy-paste and compile the code. But could you tell whether compiler complains about the undefined namespace, or the undefined function ? Usually it is needed for functions to be declared before using them. You can define it later, though.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem, but you respect your namespace `Bushman` by **not** adding `using namespace Bushman;` to the code; you should respect the namespace `std` in the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could forward declare the function, inside its namespace, before `main`:

```
namespace Bushman
{
  void to_lower(char* s);
}    

int main()
{
  // as before
}
```

Comment: Oh yes...It is a simple method and I didn't guess it. Thank you.

Comment: And then I would advise to define the function like `void Bushman::to_lower(char* s)` (rather than "re-open" the namespace)

Comment: @gx_ that depends completely from *where* you want to define it, and what helper functions, typedefs etc. you might need in namespace `Bushman`

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure what you are asking about, but I suppose it's like with normal functions/variables.

Should work if you add `namespace Bushman{}` before `main()` and then declare it fully after.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think of it. Thanks.